# How do you inherit or extend an existing yocto machine configuration?

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake

I'm working with the K26 and kv260-starter-kit in preparation for a future product based on the k26 SOM (call it the m123, for example). When I bitbake with `MACHINE=kv260-starter-kit`:

```
bitbake m123-image
```

I get a bootable result copying the following files to the 'boot' partition of my SD card:

- Image
- boot.scr
- boot.bin
- petalinux-initramfs...cpio.gz.u-boot
- devicetree/system-top-zynqmp-sck-kv-g-revB.dtb (as system.dtb)

The filesystem is untar'd to the 'root' partition of my SD card, as well.
**This bootable system works correctly.**

When I change to `MACHINE=m123`, and simply copy-paste the *kv260-starter-kit.conf* into my new *m123.conf*:

```
#@TYPE: Machine
#@NAME: M123    
#@DESCRIPTION: Dev hardware for the M123
 
#### Preamble
MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "${@['', 'kv260-starter-kit:']['kv260-starter-kit' != '${MACHINE}']}"
MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "k26-kv:"
#### Regular settings follow
 
require conf/machine/starter-kit-common.inc
 
IMAGE_BOOT_FILES += " devicetree/system-top-zynqmp-sck-kv-g-revB.dtb;system.dtb"
 
#### No additional settings should be after the Postamble
#### Postamble
PACKAGE_EXTRA_ARCHS:append = "${@['', ' kv260_starter_kit']['kv260-starter-kit' != "${MACHINE}"]}"
```

Running the same bitbake command as above results in what look like the correct files, which are copied over from the *tmp/deploy/images/m123/* folder, instead, but result in the following, paraphrased, bootup:

```
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
model=SMK-K26-XCL2G
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1 is current device
Scanning mmc 1:1...
Found U-Boot script /boot.scr
2792 bytes read in 24 ms (113.3 KiB/s)
## Executing script at 20000000
Trying to load boot images from mmc1
22403584 bytes read in 1475 ms (14.5 MiB/s)
45696 bytes read in 30 ms (1.5 MiB/s)
** No boot file defined **
Wrong Ramdisk Image Format
Ramdisk image is corrupt or invalid
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 00100000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x100000
   Loading Device Tree to 000000000fff1000, end 000000000ffff27f ... OK
 
Starting kernel ...
 
//...
 
[    4.371835] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[    4.470245] VFS: Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
 
//...
 
[    4.750234] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
 
//...
 
[    4.835820] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---
```

I don't understand the OVERRIDES and MACHINEOVERRIDES mechanism properly, but I believe that the issue from the copy-pasted *kv260-starter-kit.conf* is the following portion(s), because, of course, `MACHINE=m123` in this case:

```
['kv260-starter-kit' != '${MACHINE}']
```

I get a wholly unusable build result when I simply replace occurrences of `kv260-starter-kit` with `m123` in my *m123.conf*, I presume because there's a lot of missed OVERRIDEs for k26 and kv260 build tasks.

What do I need to change to be able to "inherit" all of the kv260 build behavior, for now, while working to append the *m123.conf* for any incremental changes I make while developing this product (and waiting for production hardware)?

Thanks for any help you can offer even if its just trial-and-error suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The means of "inheriting" behaviors or tasks from one machine to another isn't entirely clear to me still, but I was pointed to using the following command to search through all of my recipes for the `kv260` string in order to determine what behavior might need to be copied for the `m123` machine.  I found that the *boot.scr* parameters were modified for the `kv260` in *meta-som/recipes-core/u-boot/u-boot-zynq-scr.bbappend*.

In order to create the *boot.scr* for the `m123`, I created */meta-proj/recipes-core/u-boot/u-boot-zynq-scr.bbappend*, replacing instances of `kv260-starter-kit` with `m123`:

```
BOOTMODE:m123 = "generic"
BOOTFILE_EXT:m123 = ""

RAMDISK_IMAGE1:m123 = "${INITRAMFS_IMAGE}-m123.cpio.gz.u-boot"
KERNEL_IMAGE:m123 = "Image"

QSPI_RAMDISK_OFFSET:m123 = "0x4000000"
QSPI_FIT_IMAGE_OFFSET:m123 = "0xF40000"
NAND_RAMDISK_OFFSET:m123 = "0x7800000"
NAND_FIT_IMAGE_OFFSET:m123 = "0x4180000"
```

The resultant *boot.scr* and machine images now properly boot.